# How to dump and XML file from a Workflow

Tags: list

I would like to dump an XML file to a specific location based on a workflow. Whenever someone creates an element on my list I want to create an XML file and save it to a disk location.

Any good ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Use a Code Activity and write some code and set a workflow to be triggered whenever an item is added/updated.

Another approach could be having an asynchronous list item receiver - by far more easy to implement, so you don't have to walk down the Workflow craziness lane...

Comment: Might choose the list item receiver - just wondered if a WF solution might be useful

Answer (score 0):

If you want a wokflow solution, [Nintex Workflow](http://www.nintex.com) offers the ability to create XML and store them to a file share with their workflow actions.

Comment: Nintex is just a very expensive solution.

Comment: Depending on your farm and version, yes it can be.  It is also infinately more powerful than SharePoint Designer.